# Why are my [span3] classes misaligned in IE?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

The page is fine in all browser except IE (of course).
Url is http://www.efi-us.com/products/glass-applications/

[image: the issue]

Comment: how did you want these to line up?

Comment: Like this http://i.imgur.com/9oo3cSD.png

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in Chrome either.  I didn't test other browsers, but the problem should exist in every browser.

**Problem 1:** On line 91 in your style, remove the `margin-bottom: 1px;` for the following style: `.row [class*="span"]:first-child`

**Problem 2:** You have a `.row` wrapped around the first four elements, and then the next 2 elements.  Each "row" is going to start on a new line.

**Problem 3:** There are some erroneous `</p>` tags lying around... that seems to be messing with IE's parser.

**Problem 4:** You are not closing all of your `<h3>` tags.  This is also messing with IE's parser.

Using a [markup validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) will make you a better coder.

Comment: Here are screenshots for me in Firefox and Chrome:  http://i.imgur.com/OE6Fj0X.png and  http://i.imgur.com/OE6Fj0X.png To me, all h3s are closed and there arnt even any p tags in my code at all.

Comment: You have clearly updated your code since I posted (I still have the original hanging out in a textedit window).  IE now looks fine on my end.  With your new code, I can see that you still have an erroneous closing `</p>` tag immediately after every image... .  Also, if you shrink your browser windows down in Chrome and FF, you will see 3 on a row, then 1, then 2.  That doesn't appear to be the behavior you are going for (See #2 in my answer above).

Comment: Your problem is IE8 and the fact that it doesn't support media queries.  You need to make sure that your `.span3` width is set appropriately across all media queries.